# NixOs 20.03 displayManager.defaultSession not available

Tags: configuration, nixos, i3

I am trying to build my nix config with i3 as a display manager.

I copied the following from the documentation:

```hs
services.xserver.displayManager.defaultSession = "none+i3";
```

However, if I build the configuration, nix tells me that

```
The option 'services.xserver.displayManager.defaultSession' defined in "..." does not exist
```

[this is my complete config](https://github.com/faeblDevelopment/nixconfig)
the file that should setup i3 looks like this:

```hs
{ pkgs, ... }:
{
  # UI
  environment.pathsToLink = [ "/libexec" ]; # links /libexec from derivations to /run/current-system/sw 

  services.xserver.displayManager.defaultSession = "none+i3";
  services.xserver = {
    enable = true;
    layout = "us";

    desktopManager = {
      xterm.enable = false;
    };

    windowManager.i3 = {
      enable = true;
      extraPackages = with pkgs; [
        dmenu i3status i3lock
     ];
     package = pkgs.i3-gaps;
    };
  };

}
```

I am aware that the option can be moved into the `services.xserver` block, but I wanted to test the setting in isolation.

I'm using `system.stateVersion = "20.03";`

I tried searching the documentation and configuration settings, but both tell me, that the option should exist.

Could there be another error that is linked to this one?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error. In any case, although not explictly stated, I take from your question that you're trying to configure nixos without a display manager while having i3 as a window manager. If that's so, did you try enabling autologin in the lightdm module? Btw, not that it matters a lot but it's unecessary to disable xterm as a desktop manager as this is the default option.

Comment: You need to define a desktop session: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597359/124109